# How to remove NA from deprecate_stop() message

Tags: r, rlang

When I run `deprecate_stop` from the `lifecycle` package, I get an unwanted `NA` in the resulting message:

```
library(lifecycle)
deprecate_stop("2.0.0", "foo()")
#> Error: `foo()` was deprecated in <NA> 2.0.0 and is now defunct.
```

How can I remove that NA?  It's unclear to me after reading `?deprecate_stop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify the package name `deprecate_stop("1.0.0", "mypckg::foo()")`, the `NA` will be replaced with that namespace.